# Array of structs only outputs last entry read in C

Tags: arrays, c, struct, allocation

I am reading from a file and inserting the read entries into a struct as shown:

```
typedef struct card
{
    unsigned int id;
    char* name;
    char* cost;
    unsigned int converted_cost;
    char* type;
    char* text;
    char* stats;
    enum rarity rarity;
} card_t;
```

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
     FILE *input_file;  
     input_file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
     card_t **cards = NULL;

     int cardsaccum = 0;
     char *buf = NULL;
     char *name_duplicate;
     size_t bufsiz = 0;
     ssize_t result = getline(&buf, &bufsiz, input_file);

      while (result > 0)
      {
            // COPIES BUFFER TO SAVE THE MEMORY ADDRESS
            char *stringp = buf;
            // ALLOCATES MEMORY
            cards = realloc(cards, sizeof(card_t *) * num_entries);
            cards[cardsaccum] = malloc(sizeof(card_t));

            name_duplicate = strsep(&stringp, "\"");;
            cards[cardsaccum]->name = name_duplicate;

            cardsaccum++;
            num_entries++;

            result = getline(&buf, &bufsiz, input_file);
      }
      
      for(int i = 0; i < cardsaccum; i++)
      {
          printf("%s\n",cards[i]->name);
      }

      // FREEING MEMORY
      for(i = 0; i < cardsaccum;i++)
        {
            free(cards[i]);
        }
        free(cards);
        free(buf);
        fclose(input_file);
        return 0;
}
```

The file should be reading the names of Bob, Marley, Frank. However, my output is only printing the last entry read:

```
Frank
Frank
Frank
```

Do I have a problem with my allocation of memory or is it something else? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `strsep` doesn't allocate any memory for its result.  It modifies the original string.  You keep using the same `buf`.

Answer (score 0):

The function `getline()` calls `realloc()` internally. As the result, all previous pointers originating from `buf` like `strsep(&stringp, "\"")` get *invalidated* or *overwritten*.

Note that previous `cards[X]->name` point to some location inside previous `buf`.

Make a copy of a string before processing a next line:

```
cards[cardsaccum]->name = strdup(name_duplicate);
```

other solution is setting `buf` back to `NULL` just before calling `getline`.

Comment: Thank you this makes sense now!